# What is the best practice of B2B email dimension?

Tags: marketing, e-mail

The ideal width of marketing emails is 600px, does it also apply to enterprise product emails? or it can be responsive without any max width limit?

Comment: Hi Lin. Welcome to UX StackExchange community. However, your question is more pertinent for the Graphic Design community as a mailer would be opened on many different screen sizes and many different layouts. You might even have to consider a responsive mailer so I suggest you take their help for this

Comment: Well i would say that the best way would be not to have a picture at all. None of the people that i work with can aactually see the images in B2B email sent to us, unbless we purposefully turn them on for that mail, which never happens. (ok it seems that the system has a counter aaand it say sthat i have in fact not looked at one those pictures in 5 years)

Answer (score 1):

**Responsive** design is preferable, making a set hard coded width undesirable. Far more people view web content, including emails, on mobile devices today. Unlike 10-15 years ago where you could be certain every email was seen on a desktop/laptop, today there's really no telling if the viewing deice is 320px wide, 700+px wide or 1000+px wide.

The only real thorn is Outlook or luddites still using circa 2001 email clients. There should be *some* attention to fallbacks, but overall there comes a point where you simply can't support things 15 years old.

Truth is though, even with responsive design things aren't that bad for Outlook users provide you try and avoid the more "cutting edge" CSS3 features out there, or plan ahead for them failing. (Don't use @font-face, CSS shadows, transformations, filters, etc)